# Javascript to download and process GTFS zip file

Tags: javascript, gtfs

I try to download, unzip and process a `GTFS` file in zip format. Downloading and unzipping are working, but I get error message when try to use txt files with `gtfs-utils` module in `gtfsFunc()`. Output is undefined. Delays are hardcoded just for testing purpose.

```
const dl = new DownloaderHelper('http://www.bkk.hu/gtfs/budapest_gtfs.zip', __dirname);
dl.on('end', () => console.log('Download Completed'))
dl.start();

myVar = setTimeout(zipFunc, 30000);
function zipFunc() {
    console.log('Unzipping started...');
    var zip = new AdmZip("./budapest_gtfs.zip");
    var zipEntries = zip.getEntries();
    zip.extractAllTo("./gtfsdata/", true);
  }

myVar = setTimeout(gtfsFunc, 40000);
function gtfsFunc() {
    console.log('Processing started...');
    const readFile = name => readCsv('./gtfsdata/' + name + '.txt')
    const filter = t => t.route_id === 'M4'

    readStops(readFile, filter)
    .then((stops) => {
        const someStopId = Object.keys(stops)[0]
        const someStop = stops[someStopId]
        console.log(someStop)
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details on readCsv process? Just to make sure that the readCsv process is working well first. Like this:
```readCsv('./gtfsdata/' + name + '.txt')
  .on('error', console.error)
  .on('data', console.log)```

Comment: @ChickenSoups : No, I get same error, undefined. I checked path again, given folder is located in project root.

Comment: It's possible to you show us the readCsv and readStops functions also? So this way we could reproduce your code 100%.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto : These are part of module: https://github.com/public-transport/gtfs-utils#readcsvpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ChickenSoups said, you are trying to filter stops files with route_id field and this txt doesnt have this field.

The fields that stops has are:

```
stop_id, stop_name, stop_lat, stop_lon, stop_code, location_type, parent_station, wheelchair_boarding, stop_direction
```

Perhaps what you need is read the Trips.txt file instead Stops.txt, as this file has `route_id` field.
And you can accomplish this using readTrips function:

```
const readTrips = require("gtfs-utils/read-trips");
```

And your gtfsFunc would be:

```
function gtfsFunc() {

  console.log("Processing started...");
  const readFile = (name) => {
    return readCsv("./gtfsdata/" + name + ".txt").on("error", console.error);
  };

  //I used 5200 because your Trips.txt contains routes id with this value
  const filterTrips = (t) => t.route_id === "5200";

  readTrips(readFile, filterTrips).then((stops) => {
    console.log("filtered stops", stops);
    const someStopId = Object.keys(stops)[0];
    const someStop = stops[someStopId];
    console.log("someStop", someStop);
  });
}
```

Or if what you really want is to read Stops.txt, you just need to change your filter

```
const filter = t => t.route_id === 'M4'
```

to use some valid field, for example:

```
const filter = t => t.stop_name=== 'M4'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Stop** data don't have **route_id** field.

You should try other data, such as **Trip** or **Route**

You can look at the first row in your data file to see which field do they have.

[GTFS data structure here](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/examples/gtfs-feed)